# Understanding braces in grep

Tags: grep

I am reading 'Learning the bash' by Cameron NewHam. In that book there is the following lines of code
`

```
function lsd
{
    date=$1
    ls -l | grep -i "^.\{42\}$date" | cut -c55-
}
```

`
I am trying to understand the significance of {} in here {42}. I see that the backslashes are escaping the brace but I am finding it hard to understand what role the braces play in this regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, braces containing numbers after an expression indicate repetition. In this regular expression, `.\{42\}` means to match 42 of any character, `.`.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, `{n}` means "match `n` of the previous character".  In this case, the expansion is "`^`: at the start of the string, `.`: match any character, `{42}` 42 times, `$date`: followed by this text (which is `$date`, which is `$1`, which is whatever you passed into `lsd`)".

Comment: `{n}` isn't limited to repeated characters. It means repetition for groups and other pieces of an expression as well.

Comment: thanks guys, is there any specific site that i should visit to learn regular expressions or would like regular expressions in java suffice. I am a java programmer and have studied regular expressions there. i know from experience that there are slight differences in the way regular expressions are constructed for Javascript and Java and was wondering if so is the case for Unix and if yes then what would be the best place to learn them. Any recommendations will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what confused you were the `\` -> escapes.

First of all there different compliances, mainly: BRE (b:Basic), ERE( E: Extended) and PCRE (PC: Perl compatible)

for the tool grep, default it uses `BRE`, which means, for those chars with special meaning like `(, ), |, {, }...` you have to escape them to **give** them the special meaning. in your example it was `\{n\}`, to repeat the previous char/group `n` times. Without escaping them, they are just literal string.

if you used `egrep or grep -E` `ERE` then plays the role. with ERE, we escape those chars with special meaning to **deprive** the special meaning from them, which means `\{42\}` with `ERE` means literal string `"{42}"`.

some grep implementations have option `-P` to support `PCRE`, in terms of escaping, `PCRE` is same as `ERE`